# ROS Answers SE migration: Custom message

Tags: ros, message, geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hellow all !

I'm trying to create a custom message using Geomety messages and std msgs. But I can't seem to link it correctly. I've been following this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Common_step_for_msg_and_srv) but so far I'm having this error :

```
CMake Error at /home/malcolm/ros_ws/hydro_ws/catkin_ws/build/Tobot/open_tld_3d/cmake/open_tld_3d-genmsg.cmake:3 (message):
  Could not find messages which
  '/home/malcolm/ros_ws/hydro_ws/catkin_ws/src/Tobot/open_tld_3d/msg/square.msg'
  depends on.  Did you forget to specify generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)?

  Cannot locate message [point] in package [open_tld_3d] with paths
  [['/home/malcolm/ros_ws/hydro_ws/catkin_ws/src/Tobot/open_tld_3d/msg']]
```

Indeed you can find **point** in geometry_msgs and in my CMakeList.txt I added that:

```
generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   geometry_msgs
   std_msgs
 )
```

So for my understanding, it should be able to find **Point**...

This is my square.msg in case :

```
point x
point y
float64 width
float64 height
```

Nothing really complexe and I'm pretty sure I'm missing something trivial but still...

Thanks a lot !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173145/custom-message/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-06-09

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-06-10**:
Indeed that was it ! I didn't think you'll need it because yu don't have std_psgs in front of the float64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Should this be geometry_msgs/Point instead of point?

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LockBall](https://answers.ros.org/users/46201/lockball/) on 2019-09-25**:
Just wanted to say thanks for this, fixed my issue. I was thinking the same thing as Maya, i.e. std.msgs wasnt necessary for string or float or int so why would geometry_msgs be necessary for Point. Im wondering where you found this information or maybe you just 'knew' it.

**Comment by [gachiemchiep](https://answers.ros.org/users/56852/gachiemchiep/) on 2020-10-28**:
In my case I need a msg that have list of Point.
Your comment work like a charm.

geometry_msgs/Point[] points